# Deleted NetworkServices - How to recover and will the PC work?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Our junior-admin at university deleted the NetworkServices directory in Documents and Settings on all local computers. Will the PC work (AD Authentication) and can I just copy the NetworkServices directory from another PC?
I'm a Linux admin who has to fix this mess, so I need your advice!

Comment: What version of windows are the PCs?

Comment: ErnieTheGeek its Windows XP Professional

Answer (score 1):

That's the network service profile folder, which is a user folder for the built-in network service account.  The purpose of that account is to authenticate the computer to the domain for the purpose of accessing certain resources on the network. See the below article for a bit more information on local/network service accounts.

http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/services/understanding-the-local-service-and-network-service-accounts

If I remember correctly, Windows XP will just restore the folder upon reboot.  I would recommend, if you have a desktop that you can afford to "break", simply rebooting a machine and checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

That should just be the profile for the NetworkServices account.  The folder should recreate itself when the PC reboots.  The easy way to check would to be take a test machine and reboot it then check the event log for error messages.